# how to pass variables in hive using hue

Tags: hadoop, parameters, hive, hue

I will pass variables, 
I try this

```
SET x = 'user';
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE user == @user
```

but I have one error

Then I will try

```
set x='user';
select * from foo where user == '${hiveconf:x}'
```

but I have error:

```
 error while compiling statement: failed: parseexception line   
 1:38 missing eof at 'user' near ''''
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the proper notation for what you are trying to achieve:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE user = ${hiveconf:x};
```

Note that there is no need to surround `${hiveconf:x}` with quotes, and also that the comparison operator is `=`, not `==`.  From the [Hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-RelationalOperators) on relational operators, we have these two excerpts:

> A = B
>   TRUE if expression A is equal to expression B otherwise FALSE.
>
> A == B
>   Fails because of invalid syntax. SQL uses =, not ==.

So, given the following silly test table:

```
hive> SELECT user, fullname FROM foo;
OK
other_user  Bar Bazfoo
user        Foo Barbaz
Time taken: 0.228 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

Your query may look something like the following:

```
hive> SET x='user';
hive> SELECT * FROM foo WHERE user = ${hiveconf:x};
OK
user        Foo Barbaz
Time taken: 0.229 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```